# NPM Error When Installing Google Coder On Raspberry Pi

Tags: node.js, npm, raspberry-pi, raspbian

I'm doing the following on Raspberry Pi to get Google Coder set up:

```
sudo apt-get install nodejs npm git
git clone https://github.com/googlecreativelab/coder
cd coder/coder-base/
npm install
```

It works fine until I enter the 4th command "npm install" when I do that I get the following errors:

> npm ERR! Error: failed to fetch from registry: express/3.1.0
>     npm ERR!     at /usr/share/npm/lib/utils/npm-registry-client/get.js:139:12
>     npm ERR!     at cb (/usr/share/npm/lib/utils/npm-registry-client/request.js:31:9)
>     npm ERR!     at Request._callback (/usr/share/npm/lib/utils/npm-registry-client/request.js:136:18)
>     npm ERR!     at Request.callback (/usr/lib/nodejs/request/main.js:119:22)
>     npm ERR!     at Request. (/usr/lib/nodejs/request/main.js:212:58)
>     npm ERR!     at Request.emit (events.js:88:20)
>     npm ERR!     at ClientRequest. (/usr/lib/nodejs/request/main.js:209:10)
>     npm ERR!     at ClientRequest.emit (events.js:67:17)
>     npm ERR!     at CleartextStream.socketErrorListener (http.js:1188:9)
>     npm ERR!     at CleartextStream.emit (events.js:67:17)
>     npm ERR! You may report this log at:
>     npm ERR!     http://bugs.debian.org/npm
>     npm ERR! or use
>     npm ERR!     reportbug --attach /home/pi/coder/coder-base/npm-debug.log npm
>     npm ERR! 
>     npm ERR! System Linux 3.10.25+
>     npm ERR! command "/usr/bin/nodejs" "/usr/bin/npm" "install" "-g"
>     npm ERR! cwd /home/pi/coder/coder-base
>     npm ERR! node -v v0.6.19
>     npm ERR! npm -v 1.1.4
>     npm ERR! message failed to fetch from registry: express/3.1.0
>     npm ERR! 
>     npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
>     npm ERR!     /home/pi/coder/coder-base/npm-debug.log
>     npm not ok

I then tried running with "sudo npm install -g" which runs for a longer time but then fails with the same error.

I also tried running "sudo npm config set registry http://registry.nmpjs.org/pi-gpio"

Could somebody point me in the correct direction to fix or workaround this issue?

Comment: Looks like connectivity issues as it tries to pull down various dependencies.  Does your pi have a solid network connection?

Comment: Yeh. I was able to sudo apt-get update and upgrade earlier and it pulled down a lot of stuff.  I've been pinging the RPi for last few hours and it's not dropping any packets.

Comment: That is not a valid registry you set. Put only `http://registry.npmjs.org/`

Comment: I had tried running "sudo npm config set registry http://registry.npmjs.org" too but the error is still the same.

Answer (score 4):

I recently had similar issues on my pi, the reason being that the version of node/npm that are installed by apt-get are not up to date. I followed the instructions on the node wiki for debian wheezy (build from source) and it worked great (although it will take a while):

1. Install node:

```
sudo apt-get install python g++ make checkinstall fakeroot
src=$(mktemp -d) && cd $src
wget -N http://nodejs.org/dist/node-latest.tar.gz
tar xzvf node-latest.tar.gz && cd node-v*
./configure
fakeroot checkinstall -y --install=no --pkgversion $(echo $(pwd) | sed -n -re's/.+node-v(.+)$/\1/p') make -j$(($(nproc)+1)) install
sudo dpkg -i node_*
```

2. Install npm:

```
curl https://www.npmjs.org/install.sh | sudo sh
```

Original instructions are [here](https://github.com/joyent/node/wiki/Installing-Node.js-via-package-manager).

Comment: thank you for replying. If I already have node and npm installed do I need to remove them before following the steps you have outlined above?

Comment: I don't know if you have to but I did remove it via apt-get before proceeding (don't remember the exact steps, but something like sudo apt-get remove nodejs)

Answer (score 1):

try this

> npm config set registry http://registry.npmjs.org/

Comment: Tried this.  Still the similar error but this time it fails to fetch consolidate/0.8.0. error failed to fetch from registry: consolidate/0.8.0